# Inject Vue Component into web page using Quasar bex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, browser-extension

I'm building a browser extension using Quasar BEX and I want to show a Vue component in the loaded web page. I already tried to use content script hook to add raw html and css in the web page, but I want to add a component from my `src/components` folder which is also using Quasar components like `q-btn` etc.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i've managed to solve it
I'm writing the solution , so may be someone else can found it useful
I used `iframe`  to inject my component OR page into the loaded web page

First i created a new route, say `test` in **routes.js** like

```
{
  name: "test",
  path: "/test",
  component: () => import("pages/test.vue"),
},
```

Then i created an iframe and loaded that specific route
in **content-script.js** like

```
function createIframe() {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.width = "220px";
  iframe.height = "220px";

  Object.assign(iframe.style, {
    position: "fixed",
    border: "none",
    zIndex: "10000",
  });

  // load that specific page 
  iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("www/index.html#test");

  return iframe;
}
```

You can set your iframe width and height and other things you may need
Then you can use it as an element to inject anywhere like

```
document.body.prepend(createIframe());
```

Here we go ! :)

Comment: Hello. In which file do you add `document.body.prepend(createIframe());
`?

Comment: @VictorMHerasmePerez in `content-script.js`?

Comment: @DavidWolf Thanks, I will try it. Seems obvious but never used quasar to build an extension